# Database for Reporting / analytics on 1TB data with a simple model

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, nosql, analytics, business-intelligence

Big data = 1TB increasing by 10% every year.
Model is simple.. one table with 25 columns.
No joins with other tables.

I'm looking to do simple query filtering on a subset of the 25 columns.

I'd guess a traditional SQL store with indexes on the filtered columns is what's necessary. Hadoop is overkill and won't make sense as this is for a real time service. MongoDB? a bi engine like pentaho?

Any recommendations?

Comment: Any commercial Data Warehouse solution will do, e.g. check DB2 products

Comment: What did you go for in the end then? And did it work well?

Comment: I ended up using http://www.elasticsearch.org/  awesome!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that traditional solution indeed sounds fine, unless there will not be any significant changes to the really simple model as you've described it.

NoSQL sounds like not the best choice for BI / Reporting.

Get a good hardware. Spend time on performance tests and build all the required indexes. Implement a proper new data upload strategy. Implement table-level [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html) in PostgreSQL according to your needs and performance tests.

P.S. If I could have a chance now to switch from ORACLE/DB2, I would definitely go for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest investigating Infobright here - it's column-based & compressing, so you won't store the full TB, has a open-source version so you can try it out without being called by a bunch of salespeople (but last time I looked the OSS version was missing some really useful stuff, so you may end up wanting a license). Last time I tried it, it looked to the outside world like MySQL, so not hard to integrate. When I last checked it out, it was single-server-oriented, and claims to work with up to 50TB on a single server.  I *think* that Infobright can sit behind Pentaho if you decide to move in that direction.

Something infobright had going for it was it was pretty close to no-admin - there's no manual indexing, or index maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a column store would help.  depends how you're handling inserts, and if you ever have to do updates. But as well as infobright if you're going commercial, then checkout vectorwise, it's quicker and similar priced.

If you want free/open source, then check out Luciddb - There's not many docs, but it is very good at what it does!

If you want unbelievable speed, then check out vectorwise.  I believe it's about the same price as infobright, but much faster.